# Why is my LVM volume showing as being mounted multiple times?

Tags: linux, usb, mount, arch-linux, lvm

Just noticed a weird thing in the output of `lsblk`:

[image: Screenshot]

It shows that it’s mounted multiple times for each physical volume. It doesn’t seem to be causing any issues. But I’m very curious why it’s doing that and whether it's the sign of a problem waiting to happen?

I'm running Arch Linux, and the volume is located across two drives attached via USB 3.0 enclosure. I’ve had problems with the enclosure resetting and drives hitting bad blocks, but most of the time lately it’s working fine.

Is it the kind of thing where it’s resetting, automatically remounting, and somehow not unmounting the previous mount? It seems weird that it would be allowed to do that, but Linux can seem pretty weird a lot of the time so I don’t know. What are people’s thoughts?